# Change the Fig. and Number order

Tags: numbering

in my language it is required that figure number comes first before "Fig.". Maybe someone knows how to change the order so I would have "1 Fig" instead of "Fig. 1"? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `babel` package implements figure caption conventions for many languages.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel}
\begin{document}
Žiūrėkite šį paveikslą:
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\fbox{tai figūra }
\caption{Paveikslo pavyzdys}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

For completeness: the `caption` package allows you to customize caption formats. The label can be defined using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat`, where you can use arguments `#1` for the label text and argument `#2` for the label number. To put the number first you can define the format

`#2 #1`

using this command. The label itself can be set using the key `name` for a specific float type, such as `figure`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{numfirst}{#2 #1}
\captionsetup{labelformat=numfirst}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\fbox{figure contents}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]